# Add Colors in Combo box in .NET Windows application

Tags: c#

How to add 'Colors' (not color name, color itself ) as an item in combo box in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use an owner drawn combobox.  [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/ownerdrawncombobox.aspx) on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/) is a good reference.

Comment: Is there no other hack or trick for this ? I do believe there would be custom controls just for this purpose.

Comment: I'm sure there are third party controls that support this, sure.  I do not believe (but I have been wrong before) it is supported out of the box with Windows Forms.

Answer (score 1):

If you desire the color picker that is provided when you place an object with a color typed property in a PropertyGrid then [this person has done just that](http://www.vbinfozine.com/a_colorpicker.shtml) however they did it as a button with a drop down.

If you really wish it to be a ComboBox you shouldn't find that too much trouble I should think.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code I used to load list of colors to a combo for user to select:

```
List<string> colorslist = new List<string>();

string[] allColors = Enum.GetNames(typeof(System.Drawing.KnownColor));
string[] systemEnvironmentColors = new string[(typeof(System.Drawing.SystemColors)).GetProperties().Length];

int index = 0;

foreach (MemberInfo member in (typeof(System.Drawing.SystemColors)).GetProperties())
{
    systemEnvironmentColors[index++] = member.Name;
}

foreach (string color in allColors)
{
    if (Array.IndexOf(systemEnvironmentColors, color) < 0)
    {
                    colorslist .Add(color);
    } 
}

cboColors.DataSource = colorslist;
```